# MongoDB aggregation query using spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation

```
db.getCollection('questionbank').aggregate([
{ "$group": {
        "_id": {
        "technology": "$technology",
       "level":"$level",
         "type":"$type"
    },
    "Count": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.technology",
    "QuestionCount": { 
        "$push": { 
            "level":"$_id.level",
            "type":"$_id.type",
            "count": "$Count"
        },
    }
}}
])
```

I am trying to get the same output structure.

Can  anyone  please  help me  to  write  above  query  in  spring. 
I  have  tried  a  lot  but  failed.

Comment: Output of above query is -
    {
    "_id" : "Angular",
    "QuestionCount" : [ 
        {
            "level" : "TOUGH",
            "type" : "NON_CODE",
            "count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "level" : "TOUGH",
            "type" : "CODE",
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "level" : "EASY",
            "type" : "NON_CODE",
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "level" : "MEDIUM",
            "type" : "CODE",
            "count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}

And i want the same output structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following .

```
group("technology", "level", "type").count().as("count"),            group("_id.technology")                .push(                    new BasicDBObject("level", "$_id.level")                        .append("type", "$_id.type")                        .append("count", "$count"))                .as("questionCount")
```